# How to get symfony validator violations as a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, symfony

By default symfony validator violations looks like this

```
  [0] => -message: "This value should not be blank."
         -propertyPath: "name"
  [1] => -message: "This value should not be blank."
         -propertyPath: "productVarieties[0].name"
```

How can I convert this to a multidimensional array, so that productVarieties[0] will be nested inside a root array key?

I've tried using the property access component, but it seems like property path is in the wrong format

```
foreach ($violations as $violation) {
    $this->propertyAccessor->setValue($errors, $violation->getPropertyPath(), $violation->getMessage());
}
```

> Exception class:
>   "Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\NoSuchPropertyException"
>   message: "Cannot write property "name" to an array. Maybe you should
>   write the property path as "[name]" instead?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to add a object property to an array which can not be done.

According to the error the element `0` of array `productVarieties` is an array itself. It needs to be a object to assign a property to it.

For workaround you can initialize it as a stdclass object first like

```
$this->propertyAccessor->setValue($errors, 'productVarieties[0]', new \stdClass);
```

or you can replace `productVarieties[0].name` with `productVarieties[0][name]`.

I haven't worked with symphony but it should help.

Comment: So I have to do this manually for each property that is an array/collection?

Comment: No you need to design a utility function for common uses. Such as `explode` the string from `.` and then accessing the exploded values separately

Comment: Ok, I ended up creating a "ValidationContainer" class with values filled in by Symfony propertyAccessor trough __get and __set  methods + an \ArrayAccess class for collections.Thanks for your answer.